# Connect Java to remote DB2 from neatbeands

Tags: java, jdbc, db2

I'm trying to do a small application that take some data from a db by connecting to a remote DB2 server using following example:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class ConnectionExample 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String jdbcClassName="com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver";
        String url="jdbc:db2://localhost:50000/exampledb";
        String user="db2inst1";
        String password="password";

        Connection connection = null;
        try {
            //Load class into memory
            Class.forName(jdbcClassName);
            //Establish connection
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            if(connection!=null){
                System.out.println("Connected successfully.");
                try {
                    connection.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

    }

}
```

I get this error:

```
com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlException: [jcc][10389][12245][3.67.27] Errore nel caricamento della libreria nativa db2jcct2, java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no db2jcct2 in java.library.path:  ERRORCODE=-4472, SQLSTATE=null
```

further infromation here: 
http://www.justexample.com/wp/connect-db2-java/
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21419978

I don't understand where to find missing library, on the JDBC library downloaded from the IBM site is missing, have I to copy it from the remote DB2 server or I have to point to the remote location?

thanks in advance best regards.

Comment: It doesn't look like you've properly included the JDBC binaries within the project. The .jar file must be referenced in the Build Path. You can set this up within the project Properties.

Comment: Are you positive that the JDBC URL posted in your code above is what the application is using?  To get the error about `db2jcct2` you would usually need to have a URL for Type 2 connection, like `jdbc:db2:exampledb`

Comment: @IanBjorhovde can you pls.give me further information? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found specific package inside IBM embedded software

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you know how to add a jar file in the library of the app. The driver that you are looking for can be found in the IBM folder that generates when you install DB2.

For the driver go to C:/Program Files/IBM/SQLIB/Java  there you can find the db2jcc.